# Sed String manipulation

Tags: linux, sed

I need help
From a list I would like to get the addition of characters like the example below:
Start:

```
1
1
13
5
14
4
1
5
12
7
8
9
4
18
3
20
11
17
13
```

===============================================
Final results :

```
9001
9001
9013
9005
9014
9004
9001
9005
9012
9007
9008
9009
9004
9018
9003
9020
9011
9017
9013
```

this command does not work:

```
sed "s/^/9000/g" file.txt
```

Comment: `sed` is not the best command for your task. Use bash's for-loop as explained in the answers.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/^/0000/;s/^0*(.{3})$/9\1/' file
```

Prepend zeroes to the front of the number. Prepend a `9` and remove excess zeroes.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
 for num in 1 1 13 5 14 4 1 5 12 7 8 9 4 18 3 20 11 17; do echo "$(($num + 9000))"; done
```

If you also have numbers in the list, which you don't want to process, because they are already in the 90XX format you can throw in an if statement:

```
for num in 1 1 13 5 14 4 1 5 12 7 8 9 4 18 3 20 11 17 9005; do if [ $(($num)) -le 9000 ]; then echo "$(($num + 9000))"; else echo $num; fi; done
```

[For loop in bash](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-for-loop/) - for; do; done;

Bash arithmetic expression to add the numbers - [$((EXPR))](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arithexp.html)

Comment: the problem occurs when this string is present in the list:
1 1 13 5 14 4 1 5 12 7 8 9 4 18 3 20 11 17 9014 9005 9007 9008
how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please include _complete_ example and explain what is the end result you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you.

```
for num in `cat file.txt`; do if [ $num -le 9000 ]; then echo "$(($num + 9000))"; else echo $num; fi; done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/.*/echo $((9000+&))/e' infile
```